# How to ensure AWS Elastic Beanstalk is free

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am wanting to deploy a Django webapp with a PostgreSQL database to AWS Elastic Beanstalk using [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html) tutorial, but I am so confused about pricing. It says it uses services in the AWS Free Tier, but those seem to be limited to a certain number of hours a month, so how do I make sure I don't go above that threshold? And how do I make sure I'm only using free services? They even require a card on file, so it seems really hard to make sure I don't get charged.

Answer (score 14):

You can do the following configuration to make sure you use AWS Elastic Beankstalk for one year free.

- Use only Micro instances for the WebServer and RDS instance.
- Limit the scaling of the WebServer maximum to 1 or use Standalone deployment without autoscaling.
- When selecting storage, use less than 30GB for EBS and don't enable Provision Throughput.

Apart from these, there are usage base costs for Network, EBS IOPS & etc which includes a free quota and the cost is not considerable when it comes to light use cases.

Answer (score 5):

I have found  "Cost Management Preferences" -> "Receive Free Tier Usage Alerts" setting in Billing preferences menu. Hopefully this will be enough for a small personal projects with low usage. I would guess it is not enough for large projects since this is only a notification.

Answer (score 3):

The [AWS Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) allows AWS accounts to use a certain amount of services for no charge. Any usage beyond the free tier limits will result in a charge on your credit card.

The Free Tier is intended to provide a trial of AWS services. It is *not* intended for production use, nor is there any guaranteed way to stay within the free limits. It is up to you to monitor your usage.

There is no such thing as a totally free AWS account.

Answer (score 2):

In short, you can absolutely make sure that your app stays free, just not from within the AWS interface. You'll have to use your own usage monitoring to ensure you stay within the free limits as others state.

As Ashan said, this is a pretty silly approach since fees are nominal and the alternative is a loss of service, however, AWS does offer APIs to help you do this through [CloudWatch](https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home).
CloudWatch exposes pretty much all of the billable metrics on a service-by-service basis, for example [here are the metrics for EC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/viewing_metrics_with_cloudwatch.html), and [here are the metrics for S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudwatch-monitoring.html). After starting your services through beanstalk, just look up all the services you're using via the billing page of the AWS console, look up the CloudWatch APIs for each, then check them.

At least for EC2, there are even customizable alarms and actions, including shutting down the instance. See the Monitoring tab at the bottom of the EC2 console. Not sure, but you might have to manually throw status updates to their status system for some of the other metrics. If so, it's not that difficult. You'd set up an access key for some IAM identity so you can check CloudWatch stuff from command line. Then, you'd write a watchdog script to run on that instance using AWSCLI to regularly ping CloudWatch and call your shutdown code or modify your status if you're over some percentage of your quota.

Comment: Quote: "You'd set up an access key for some IAM identity so you can check CloudWatch stuff from command line". Can you recommend a tutorial: docs/vid on how to get the temporary security key needed to access EB via Shell - for free? I have a hard time understanding docs related to this topic. I also don't quite understand why there is "IAM" and "IAM identity center". Entering IAM the first thing I see is a warning "Update your access permissions for AWS Billing, Cost Management, and Account consoles". It kind of sounds like they want me to allow them to charge me for giving me access in return